# Modal View navigation bar not presenting properly

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple app where I run some GET queries and fire off a modal view once they complete. The presenting view controller contains a map view with a search controller/search bar. As the modal is triggered, it presents overCurrentContext (with blur effects) as expected however the navigation bar (with cancel button) slides underneath the search bar. I can see the navigation bar is created properly (with title and cancel button) but it transitions underneath the search bar. Have I done something incorrectly?

Presenting viewController

```
func showPopOver()  {
    let fares = Fares(userLocation: userLocation, destination: userDestination)
    fares.getFares { _ in
        self.RideCosts = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RideCosts") as! RideCosts
        self.RideCosts.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.RideCosts.loadFares(fares: fares.fareArray)
        self.present(self.RideCosts, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
}
```

modalViewController (RideCosts)

```
class RideCosts: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    var fareArray: [(name: String, value: String)] = []
    var arrayOfCellData = [cellData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, at: 0)

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        self.isModalInPopover = true

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping back on this... Swift rookie mistake, I resolved the issue with the modal presentation (modal view's navigation bar presenting underneath the search bar) by setting the modalpresentationStyle to overFullScreen rather than overCurrentContext

Working code

```
func showPopOver()  {
let fares = Fares(userLocation: userLocation, destination: userDestination)
fares.getFares { _ in
    self.RideCosts = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RideCosts") as! RideCosts
    self.RideCosts.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext  //FIX
    self.RideCosts.loadFares(fares: fares.fareArray)
    self.present(self.RideCosts, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

}